# box.net API oauth refresh token without coding

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I have the box.net API client_id and client_secret . I want to get a refresh token for some box account but i don't want to create the app for it.

what is easiest way to get the API refresh token and start using the API?
maybe there is some app where i can enter my client_id, client_secret keys and then do the oauth process and finally copy my refresh token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Box Token Generator](https://box-token-generator.herokuapp.com/) app to generate an access/refresh token pair for your client id/secret.

Comment: This looks exactly what i need but it doesn't work for some reason. After i enter keys it says "redirect url mismatch".

Comment: But maybe this problem depends on my client app settings. i can enter that url in settings

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to play around with the API and prototype something, then you can create a developer token really easily. A developer token is identical to an access token except it can't be refreshed after it expires and it's only valid for your own Box account.

You can find it in your [Box application settings](https://cloud.app.box.com/developers/services) under "OAuth2 Parameters":

[image: screenshot of developer token in Box app settings]

Comment: I agree with Greg that this is the easiest way to get a developer token. However, this method has two limitations: you won't receive a refresh token (which will prevent the testing of token refresh logic), and this access token will be unable to perform certain enterprise API actions. If neither of those limitations matter to you, then I would use this method.